# How to upload .csv file to server using code in iphone(ios)?

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, csv

I want to upload .csv file on server while i get .csv file in my project . Can any one help me in that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create web service on your server that accepts data of csv file as input.
Then you can use NSURLConnection or use NSData's writeToURL:atomically: method

Comment: can u tell me in detail ? and also m facing problem in write data to .csv file .. Can u help me in that ?? I am not able to write data in .csv file .. I am only able to fatch data from iphone ...can u tell me how to write data in that .csv file ..

Comment: ya sure wait .  just c this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158592/how-to-write-csv-file-from-function . I have use function to get data of iphone .Now confuse how to write that data in .csv file ..

Comment: I am still cant upload my .csv file ..can u provide some code ??