# how to write .csv file from function?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, file-upload, csv

Hey Friends i got all contacts detail of my iphone by using this function ..

```
    -(void)collectContacts
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people  = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    //NSLog(@" the Name %@%",people);
    for(int i = 0;i<ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
        // Get First name, Last name, Prefix, Suffix, Job title 
        NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *prefix = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonPrefixProperty);
        NSString *suffix = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonSuffixProperty);
        NSString *jobTitle = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(ref,kABPersonJobTitleProperty);
        NSLog(@" the phoneType %@%",firstName);
        NSLog(@" the phoneType %@%",lastName);

        ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
        {       
            CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);   
            NSString *phoneLabel =(NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, j));
            NSString *phoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;
            NSLog(@" the phoneType %@%",phoneLabel);
            NSLog(@" the phoneNumber %@%",phoneNumber);
        }

        CFStringRef address;
        CFStringRef label;
        ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonAddressProperty);    
        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(multi); i++) 
        {           
            label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
            CFStringRef readableLabel = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(label);
            NSLog(@" Lable %@%",readableLabel);
            address = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);
            NSLog(@" Address %@%",address);
            CFRelease(address);
            CFRelease(label);
        } 

        ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        for(CFIndex idx = 0; idx < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); idx++)
        {
            CFStringRef emailRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, idx);
            NSString *strLbl = (NSString*) ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel (ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex (emails, idx));
            NSLog(@" Email Lable %@%",strLbl);
            NSString *strEmail_old = (NSString*)emailRef;
            NSLog(@" Email-Id %@%",strEmail_old);
            //[[strEmail_old componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:@"components.csv" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
        }
    }
    //[[ContactsText componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:@"components.csv" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
//  NSLog(@" Data in the .CSV file = %@%",ContactsText);
}
'
```

Now i want to make .csv file from this function's output .. and m getting all data in NSLog . I juat want to write .csv file from that data .. Can anyone help me in that ?? Data coming are proper but .csv file not gonna written ...Thanks

Comment: how to get RecorId from above code ..can u tell me ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you will have all the data in "ContactsText", try following code:

```
    NSArray  *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* savePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    savePath = [savePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"components.csv"]; 
    [[ContactsText componentsJoinedByString:@","] writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Remember that you cannot just save "components.csv" file. You have to save the file in documents folder only.

Comment: nope i dont have data in ContactsText .. i have just declare it as NSMutableArray . I am much confuse in that .. I just want to write whole data in that .csv file while i click on button .. Wht to do with that ContactsText..

Comment: There's no direct way to write code that generates csv data. You have to manually write code that pulls each entry from address book and adds it to mutable string separated by comma. Then finally write that string to a file as mentioned in above code.

Comment: ok . can u give me that code so i can do that ?? I am not getting that properly . plz need your help .Thanks

Comment: M still not getting value oin my .csv file can u help me ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many Open Source extensions that add csv support to arrays. For example [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) which is available on GitHub.

Comment: Can u tell me how to use that in my project ?? I am not getting that properly .

Comment: @Vivek2012 There is documentation for the classes. What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: can u give me link of that doc so i can refer ?? where it is  ??

Comment: @Vivek2012 - The link is the same one which I gave in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your data may contain characters that require special treatment - in the case of a CSV file most notably the comma itself. If there is a comma in the string you write out, you should put double quotes around that field. In that case, if there is already a double quote in the string, you need to escape that, too.

I would suggest that you use the `CHCSVParser` from Dave DeLong, you can find it here: http://davedelong.com/portfolio

It is worth the trouble to import a good third-party framework to make sure edge cases are handled correctly.

Comment: I am not getting that example .. I have refer that but i didn't get any thing from that ....can u help me how can i get to write data in my .csv file using that above function ??